# Laravel more than one role

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm trying to make it possible to have 2 roles and switchable.

(PHP v7.2.5 with laravel v7.30.6)

I got a server-side API and admin panel on laravel/nova, which is currently in production.
I have a users table(MySQL) and I have a role field that contains one string('Admin' or 'Client' etc) it's possible to be only one role at a time.

[user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G81or.png) This is how I check the user's role.

I tried using the Spatie roles package, but my problem is that I need to move all my production users to the new table created by Spatie, which is inefficient.

is there a good solution you know that will make it easier and faster to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware to check for example if user is admin or not.

Path: app/Http/Middleware/EnsureAdminIsValid.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class EnsureAdminIsValid
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->is_admin == 1) {
             return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/normal-role-users-page')->with('error','You are not Admin');
    }
}
```

is_admin is a table in USER table. If you already have a table change name in middleware and value can be string or boolean (true, false).

In app/Http/Kernel.php add:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [        
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureAdminIsValid::class,
```

Now you have a web middleware and you can add it to any URL or construct function of any controller.

**route:**
// Admin dashboard

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin-dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

**controller:**

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('admin'); 
    }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.
That's not exactly what I'm searching for, I'm looking for a way to make users have more than one role.

Comment: With middleware you can do that. Simply add more logic and conditions to your middleware closure related to your real situation.

Comment: I got middleware for all other roles, there is only 1 admin so I don't need to make middleware.
but still, I don't see how middleware will make the user table have two roles.

Comment: I have in my table user_level. if user level is == 1, he has all access(super admin), if 2 is admin he has all access except super admin's rights, if 3 is an agent, 4 is user and so on.

Comment: oh, that sounds like a good idea.
if I understand you correctly you mean something like this:
change the role field to be 1 or 2 or 3 etc
but in this example, I need to make all the possible combinations.
like Business, Client, Admin = 2 and Business, Client = 3, Admin, Business = 4.
is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. Yes this is what i'm doing at my site now.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly, you want your user to have multiple roles instead of only one.

You must change create a role table with a pivot table (i.e role_users) then add a belongsToMany relationship in your user model.

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

You will then have to modify the role verification logic to something like this.

```php
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->exists();
}
```

Another solution which requires less migration effort but is less scalable (i.e. if you add roles, you will need to add more and more fields to the users table):
Split the "role" column to two boolean columns `is_admin` and `is_business`.

You can then modify your isAdmin and isBusiness methods to

```php
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->is_admin === 1;
}

public function isBusiness()
{
    return $this->is_business === 1;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.
The first example is doing the same as the spatie package.
It is easy to make as your example here, but it will be hard to move all production users to it.

the second solution is possible, but not the best one.
Thanks anyway :D

Comment: You could automate the process of moving the users to the proper role with an artisan command.
Loop the users and check the "role" column. If it is an admin, assign the admin role to it, if business, assign the business role to it. You can also add custom logic to make a user an admin and a business user.
Once you are done, you can remove the "role" column from your user model.